# database from java class build by ant in linux

Tags: java, linux, hibernate, ant

I want to generate derby database using ant and build.xml (source class java as model table)? 
In normal(I mean development phase). I've no problem to build that. Just right click to the ant file and build (using eclipse) the database is generated.
The problem is when I met the implementation step (in linux). 
I'm using bin/ant -f build.xml command but its not generate and give some error like this:

```
[HibernateTools] Executing Hibernate Tool with a Hibernate Annotation/EJB3 Configuration
[HibernateTools] 1. task: hbm2ddl (Generates database schema)
[HibernateTools] log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.Version).
[HibernateTools] log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
[HibernateTools] log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Build successfull 
But i cannot find the file database is?

 Anyone with some exp? 

@ alonso hi thanks i think so, i try with -v
and give me this :

```
[root@APPTTPDEV01 TimesheetEJB_jar]# /home/rpangemanan/apache-ant-1.7.0/bin/ant  -v build.xml
Apache Ant version 1.7.0 compiled on December 13 2006
Buildfile: build.xml
Detected Java version: 1.6 in: /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_32/jre
Detected OS: Linux
parsing buildfile /home/rpangemanan/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/j2ee-apps/Timesheet/TimesheetEJB_jar/build.xml with URI = file:/home/rpangemanan/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/j2ee-apps/Timesheet/TimesheetEJB_jar/build.xml
Project base dir set to: /home/rpangemanan/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/j2ee-apps/Timesheet/TimesheetEJB_jar

BUILD FAILED
Target "build.xml" does not exist in the project "HelloWorld".
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.tsort(Project.java:1821)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.topoSort(Project.java:1729)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.topoSort(Project.java:1692)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1298)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1181)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:698)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:199)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:257)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:104)
```

Comment: can you post your `build.xml` file please?

Comment: I dont see any "errors" there. It is just a warning about log4j initialization. The error must be something else. For more information, add -verbose (or) -v to ant execution command. For more and more information, add -debug to ant command.

Comment: hi, i follow your instruction with -v

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi i finally found what the problem was 
first the builded was no error like Peter and exception says tq again. 
that is missing is in 'ij'(found on javadb\bin) i must create true the database derby like this

```
connect 'jdbc:derby://localhost/1527/timesheet_db;create=true';
```

then just build again with ant

Answer (score 1):

By default ant will always use the `build.xml`, so providing it's name should be redundant.

Providing a build **target** however is important. What you try to execute is the target `build.xml` inside the file `build.xml`, which doesn't exist in your project? Ant documentation says:

> When omitted [..*the target*..], the target that is specified in the default attribute of the project tag is used.

Try just

```
bin/ant
```

This should execute the build.xml and the default target of your project. Also did you put your ant file into the ANT_HOME directory? If not you need to specify with -f the **absolute** location of your file (like `/home/user/build.xml`).

A good practice is to add `/<path to ant>/bin` to you PATH and just use the `ant` command in the directory where your build.xml resides.

The warnings with `log4j` can be ignored. It just means, that you haven't defined a logging appender, which specifies how log messages are stored (e.g. in a file or multiple files or some other stream). In this case they are printed to the console, which should be okay for you (for now).